# a number is required in the selection criteria when using a parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am new to CR, and I think this is a complicated question. When a user runs the report, I want the user to input either nothing - which will get everything, or to input the values for that field - to get those specific values. Let me know if I am approaching this right.

I am trying to use a formula in the record selection formula editor. This formula references a parameter. I am trying to use `WrkOrder.Center` field - which is a number - in my selection criteria.

I am getting the error "a number is required here" in the record selection formula editor. I need to do a `totext` or `cstr` ? It just seems to still be incorrect.

if the center is blank then get all centers, else get the selected center input in the parameters by the users running the report.

`if {?Center}="" then true else {?Center}=cstr({WRKORDER.CENTERNBR})`

`if {?Center} = "" then true else {?Center}={WRKORDER.CENTERNBR}`

parameters to get what is either input or get all centers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to check is the data type of your parameter and the data type of database field to ensure they match.

If you edit your parameter the first three controls on the form at the top are Name, Type, and List of Values.  The Drop Down Box for Type will identify the data type of your parameter.

To identify the data type of your database field, find the field in the Field Explorer and if you don't already see a data type listed next to the column names for each table, right click on any field name and click "Show Field Type" and this will toggle the display of the field data type on and/or off.  Its usually off by default I believe.

In order to use a comparison with the = operator, these two objects must have matching data types.  You aren't able to change the data type of a database field, but you can change the data type of your parameter to match it.

Hopefully this will fix your error.  The most common cause of the error message you are receiving is when one field is a Number type and the other is a Text type.  Functions that convert the data will work in formula fields, but usually will continue to throw errors when used in selection expert formulas.